# How can I export existing links in DOORS to Excel

Tags: excel, csv, ibm-doors

I'm working with a third party that is not allowed to access DOORS but is in for the requirement and the linking to the testcases. It is no problem to export both documents in an Excel sheet. Unfortunately, the most important feature of DOORS, namely the linking between testcases and requirements will not be exported.

How can I export the links between the two modules to Excel or some other format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the Analysis→Wizard. With this, you can create DXL Layout columns that show the linked requirements, including attributes of your choice, like Object Text, Object Heading, Requirement Type or whatever. You can even create columns for recursively linked objects (Customer Req→System Req→Functional Req→Design→...).

Then export the current view to excel.

If you want the external company to create new links while they work with the excel sheet, let them create a new column in the sheet that contains the absolute number(s) of the objects to be linked, import the column to a new temporary attribute and use Link→Advanced→Link by Attribute… to create links.